# orphanRemoval=true throws org.hibernate.AssertionFailure Exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an common entity, which has a bidirectional association. The code of the entity is the next one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableName")
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ID;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "OtherEntityID", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OtherEntity> OtherEntity;

    ...
```

I try to delete the Entity with this code:

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Entity e = s.get(Entity.class, EntityID);
s.beginTransaction();
s.delete(e);
s.getTransaction().commit();
s.close();
```

However, Hibernate returns this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: collection owner not associated with session
```

If I set `orphanRemoval=false`, then I'm able to remove the entity without any problem. I've tried initializing the Collection before deleting the entity with `Hibernate.initialize()`, but nothing changed.
I suppose this has something to do with the fact that the Collection is loaded `LAZY` and not `EAGGER`, but I've not found any solution yet. Could anybody help me?

PD: I'm using Hibernate 5.2.4 Final.

Comment: Did you find an answer?